# JHipster ./mvnw -Pprod package strange behavior

Tags: webpack, jhipster, production

I have created JHipster application 
It has 74 entities generated in JDL-Studio 
In development everything is perfect, everything is working OK.
./mvnw test    says everything is OK 
yarn test      also, says everything is OK

But when i fire:

***yarn run webpack:prod***

```
[root@localhost StoVehiclesManagementSystems]# yarn run webpack:prod
yarn run v1.9.4
$ node -p process.arch && yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
x64
$ rimraf target/{aot,www}
$ yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
$ node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
(node:27830) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

After the last line cursor just keep blinking and nothing happens, NO WARNING OR ERROR MESSAGE, nothing at all.

In order to test it, i have left it for 6 hours like that and nothing changed.

Any idea what is going on?
Is there a way to force logging about what is going on in the background

PS:

I am working in Centos Linux

UPDATE:
This are logs when i execute

```
./mvnw -Pprod package


[root@localhost StoVehiclesManagementSystems]# ./mvnw -Pprod package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< com.sto.vms:sto-vehicles-management-systems >-------------
[INFO] Building Sto Vehicles Management Systems 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:copy-resources (default-resources) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 147 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 147 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-versions) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:copy-resources (docker-resources) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.1:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.1/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.4:revision (default) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[WARNING] Exception caught during execution of command '[git, config, --system, --edit]' in '/usr/local/git/bin', return code '128', error message 'fatal: Invalid path '/usr/local/git/etc': No such file or directory
'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.4.RELEASE:build-info (default) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] Node v8.11.3 is already installed.
[INFO] Yarn 1.9.2 is already installed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install --force' in /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems
[INFO] yarn install v1.9.2
[INFO] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[INFO] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[ERROR] warning Pattern ["colors@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-colors-1.3.1-4accdb89cf2cabc7f982771925e9468784f32f3d" as pattern ["colors@^1.1.2","colors@^1.1.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[ERROR] warning Pattern ["object-assign@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863" as pattern ["object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[ERROR] warning Pattern ["opn@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-opn-5.3.0-64871565c863875f052cfdf53d3e3cb5adb53b1c" as pattern ["opn@^5.1.0","opn@^5.1.0","opn@^5.3.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[ERROR] warning Pattern ["send@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-send-0.16.2-6ecca1e0f8c156d141597559848df64730a6bbc1" as pattern ["send@0.16.2","send@0.16.2"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[INFO] info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
[INFO] info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[INFO] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning " > ngx-webstorage@2.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^5.0.0".
[INFO] [5/5] Rebuilding all packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
[INFO] Done in 39.12s.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) @ sto-vehicles-management-systems ---
[INFO] yarn not inheriting proxy config from Maven
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems
[INFO] yarn run v1.9.2
[INFO] $ node -p process.arch && yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[INFO] x64
[INFO] $ rimraf target/{aot,www}
[INFO] $ yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
[INFO] $ node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
[ERROR] (node:7497) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

After the last line cursor keep blinking

Comment: With that many entities, you have 8 TypeScript files for each entity. Compiling 592 TS files probably takes a while. Start the process and go for a 20-minute walk. Come back and see if it's finished. ;)

Comment: I have left it for 6 HOURS and nothing happens.
I have updated my question with log from:
./mvnw -Pprod package

Comment: Then I don't know the answer. I've only ever had a handful of entities in my JHipster apps. 74 entities seems like a lot.

Comment: Well, it is a big complicate application with a lot of functionalities

Comment: Solved the situation by recreating application and nothing more, now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the situation by recreating application and nothing more, now it works fine